# Not able to access Apache virtual host from other machines on my local network

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am not able to connect to `mysite.com` from another computer in my network. Several relevant config files are shown below.

My `apache2.config`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:80
ServerName 157.50.13.131
Include /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ashwin-HP-Notebook
127.0.0.1   mysite.com

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My virtual host configuration file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf`):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
 ServerName mysite.com

 DocumentRoot /home/ashwin/mysite
 <Directory /home/ashwin/mysite/>
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/error.log
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mysite/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

when i try 192.168.0.100/mysite.com from a system in lan 
i get **the requested URL/mysite.com was not found on this server**

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Do you get an error? What is is?

Comment: I didn't get any error , the server runs . But when i try to access it using mysite.com from another system in the network it just says "This site can't be reached"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your hosts file on the client machine, the web server's hosts file doesn't act as a DNS resolver to other systems on your network

```
# /etc/hosts

192.168.0.100    mysite.com
```

After adding that to the client's hosts file you should be able to access mysite.com from a browser on the client